# Do some calculation using SQL directly with sequelize

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I try to do some calculation, statistics etc. But because I have some table to use, for now I retrieve all my "transactions" (entity) as object and do my calculs after retrieving all of it. But it's really heavy because I have a lot of raws. And because I can't only fetch the transaction Table (data missing) , I have to include some others models to add some subqueries parameters.

Here the request actual :

```
models.event.findOne({
where: {id: eventId},
lang: options.lang,
include: [{
    model: models.eventPricing,
    as: 'priceItems',
    attributes: ['id', 'price', 'percentFees', 'fixedFees', 'quantity', 'quantityPrinted', 'quantityPrintedUnsold', 'nameFrI18n', 'nameEnI18n'],
    through: {attributes: []},
    include: [{
        model: models.eventPricingPermission,
        as: 'permissions',
        attributes: ['id'],
        include: [{
            model: models.ticket,
            as: 'tickets',
            where: whereClause,
            required: false,
            through: {attributes: []},
            include: [
                {
                    model: models.transaction,
                    as: 'transaction'
                }
            ]
        }]
    }]
}]
})
```

What I want to do is use the same way to do my "where" by including all relations I need, but just do some calcule on it.

But I get all transactions with the custom fields. I don't want that. I would like just a result of my query with my custom fields like

```
{
'totalAmount' : XX
'totalSubTotal' : XX 
'totalDiscount' : XX 
'totalBEVfees' : XX 
'totalTransaction' : XX
}
```

So I've tried

```
models.transaction.findAll({
            lang: options.lang,
            attributes:[
                'id', 'created_at', 'amount',
                [ models.sequelize.fn('SUM',    models.sequelize.col('Transaction.amount')),    'totalAmount' ],
                [ models.sequelize.fn('SUM',    models.sequelize.col('Transaction.sub_total')), 'totalSubTotal' ],
                [ models.sequelize.fn('SUM',    models.sequelize.col('Transaction.discount')),  'totalDiscount' ],
                [ models.sequelize.fn('SUM',    models.sequelize.col('Transaction.bev_fees')),  'totalBEVfees' ],
                [ models.sequelize.fn('COUNT',  models.sequelize.col('Transaction.id')),        'totalTransaction' ]
            ],
            where : { status:'succeeded' },
            include : [{
                model : models.ticket,
                attributes : ['id', 'price'],
                as: 'tickets',
                include : [{
                    model : models.eventPricingPermission,
                    where : { idEvent : eventId},
                    as: 'access'
                }]
            }]
        })
```

And I try

```
models.transaction.sum('amount', {
            raw: true,
            lang: options.lang,
            attributes:[
                'id', 'amount', 'subTotal', 'discount', 'BEVFees', 'created_at',
                [ models.sequelize.fn('SUM',    models.sequelize.col('Transaction.amount')),    'totalAmount' ],
                [ models.sequelize.fn('SUM',    models.sequelize.col('Transaction.sub_total')), 'totalSubTotal' ],
                [ models.sequelize.fn('SUM',    models.sequelize.col('Transaction.discount')),  'totalDiscount' ],
                [ models.sequelize.fn('SUM',    models.sequelize.col('Transaction.bev_fees')),  'totalBEVfees' ],
                [ models.sequelize.fn('COUNT',  models.sequelize.col('Transaction.id')),        'totalTransaction' ]
            ],
            distinct : true,
            group:['Transaction.id'],
            where : { status:'succeeded' },
            include : [{
                model : models.ticket,
                attributes : ['id', 'price'],
                as: 'tickets',
                //through : { attributes : ['id']},
                include : [{
                    model : models.eventPricingPermission,
                    where : { idEvent : eventId},
                    through : { attributes : []},
                    as: 'access'
                }]
            }]
        })
```

too, but it's not working.

---

**EDIT :**

After updating Sequelize, I can do this

```
var query =  [
        models.transaction.sum('amount', queryClause),
        models.transaction.sum('subTotal', queryClause),
        models.transaction.sum('discount', queryClause),
        models.transaction.sum('BEVFees', queryClause),
        models.transaction.count(queryClause)
    ];
```

With queryClause equals to my options. It's working but what is worrying me it's that 5 requests to my DB. I think I can be more optimized…

---

Have you got an idea ? Or I have to use the raw query directly because it's too "custom" ?